# RAID Manager on Windows for IBM Server x-345

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, raid, ibm, ibm-xseries

Good Morning,
I have a IBM x-series 345 server with Windows Server 2003, I have a defunct drive which I would like to replace and rebuild the RAID while the server is up. I have been up and down in the IBM website and I cannot find a Windows Utility which allows me to see and manage the RAID. Can someone tell me the name of the program used to do this, or send me a link to this program.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's a hardware RAID card? It's not a Windows soft RAID setup, is it? What alerted you to the degraded RAID array?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [ServeRAID.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eserver/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdiricinfo%2Ffqy0_srm_intr.html)